# Django-Filebrowser 500 Error on Heroku + S3

Tags: django, heroku, django-storage, django-filebrowser

Getting a 500 Error using Filebrowser & S3 on Heroku upon POST. I have added the stack trace and model info :) Is it posible that this is an S3 issue or something to do with Filebrowser?

Stack trace from terminal:

```
[01/Jul/2016 05:19:10] "GET /admin/filebrowser/browse/?pop=1&dir=300x250/160x600 HTTP/1.1" 500 76295
Internal Server Error: /admin/filebrowser/browse/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/scott/Sites/banner_preview_tool_venv/banner_preview_tool/filebrowser/decorators.py", line 35, in decorator
if get_path('', site=site) is None:
File "/Users/scott/Sites/banner_preview_tool_venv/banner_preview_tool/filebrowser/decorators.py", line 18, in get_path
if site.storage.isdir(converted_path):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 205, in inner
return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'MediaStorage' object has no attribute 'isdir'
2016-07-01 05:19:14,947 ERROR Internal Server Error: /admin/filebrowser/browse/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/scott/Sites/banner_preview_tool_venv/banner_preview_tool/filebrowser/decorators.py", line 35, in decorator
if get_path('', site=site) is None:
File "/Users/scott/Sites/banner_preview_tool_venv/banner_preview_tool/filebrowser/decorators.py", line 18, in get_path
if site.storage.isdir(converted_path):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 205, in inner
return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'MediaStorage' object has no attribute 'isdir'
```

And here is the model:

```
file = FileBrowseField("HTML or ZIP File", max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, extensions=[".zip",".html"], help_text="Upload an html file or a zip file of banners")

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)

    super(BannerCode, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

def post_upload_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['file'].extension == ".zip":
        path = kwargs['path'] 
        thefile = kwargs['file'] 

        # Convert file and dir into absolute paths
        fullpath = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, '' + thefile.path)
        dirname = os.path.dirname(fullpath)

        # Get a real Python file handle on the uploaded file
        fullpathhandle = open(fullpath, 'r') 

        # Unzip the file, creating subdirectories as needed
        zfobj = zipfile.ZipFile(fullpathhandle)
        for name in zfobj.namelist():
            if name.endswith('/'):
                try: # Don't try to create a directory if exists
                    os.mkdir(os.path.join(dirname, name))
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                outfile = open(os.path.join(dirname, name), 'wb')
                outfile.write(zfobj.read(name))
                outfile.close()

        # Now try and delete the uploaded .zip file and the  __MACOSX dir if they exist.
        try:
            os.remove(fullpath)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            osxjunk = os.path.join(dirname,'__MACOSX')
            shutil.rmtree(osxjunk)
        except:
            pass                

# Signal provided by FileBrowser on every successful upload. 
filebrowser_post_upload.connect(post_upload_callback)
```

I'm not sure how to even start debugging this one. Anyone have insights on this? Thx!

Comment: Showing us a full stack trace and the code that generates the error would be a good place to start ;-).

Comment: Added above :-) thanks

Comment: Where is `MediaStorage` coming from? Please show us what storage backend you have configured.

Comment: I am defining a custom storage:- in settings.py

`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage' `

in custom_storages.py:

`from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION`

Comment: To be clear, this works just fine for standard FileUpload or ImageUpload fields.

Comment: Filebrowser is not compatible with django-storages. There is a [lengthy discussion on the issue](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser/issues/40) along with a bunch of code snippets providing workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to answer this...

Filebrowser is not compatible with django-storages.

Thanks @solarissmoke